# Blur event for composedPath returns empty array on window for Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, event-handling, onblur

I am trying to apply *composedPath* to the blur event. I have noticed however, that Safari returns an empty array for *composedPath.*

On Chrome I do get the array of size one with the window object.

Here is my jsFiddle:

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/kfL4jr3w/)

I tried looking for blur event on mdn if it is unsupported on Safari but that is not the case. Version of Safari is 15.

```js
 window.addEventListener('blur', (e)=>{
                debugger;
                console.log("Composed Path" , e.composedPath());
            });
```

```html
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is an example of a simple HTML page with one paragraph.</p>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like bug so I have raised it on WebKit bugzilla - https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=253443 and now it is fixed.

Committed - https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/commit/80b26f0e3d9ab9f091390232abbdfae07ff82476